# Processing commandline arguments

Tags: console, lua

I'm parsing commandline arguments in lua with a command parser library (`penlight lapp`). This works fine, is easy to design and flexible enough for me.
However, now I have a table containing all the parsed arguments, so I'm still stuck with the *processing*, that is calling functions or changing settings etc. within my program. Some of these options are checks or similar operations that abort normal program behaviour, so I need to exit the main program before entering the normal routines. To implement such behaviour, I'm essentially using a large if-elseif chain, which is complex and hard to maintain.

Here is some code, but my question is of a general nature: Most not-trivial-utilities-with-more-than-two-arguments need to solve this, there has to be a way to do this somewhat elegantly and non-complex. How?

```
local cmdargs = [[
    Utility

    --foo       enables foo
    --bar       check for bar, then exit
]]
local args = parse_args(cmdargs)

if args.foo then
    set_switch()
end
if args.bar then
    check_something()
    exit(0)
end
do_main_stuff()
```

My example has only two arguments, but with 20+ arguments this style becomes really unreadable.